# Elasticsearch 6.2.3 failed to parse date field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am usin the Java Api to connect to Elastic search, and I get this `[Mon Apr 16 11:56:43 EDT 2018] with format [strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis]` When I try to get data by dates. I also have some mappings, you can see then in the pastebin below. Anyone has an idea?

The mappings: https://pastebin.com/ikf2KYBk

Edit: The date it fails to parse is used in the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When sending the query, the date I was using to filter was malformed, thus causing this error.